# Running a Jupyter Notebook Fails with a 500 Error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run a simple Jupyter notebook on my local machine and I strangely run into some errors.

```
$ python --version
Python 3.11.5
```

I just run the following command:

```
$jupyter notebook
```

and when I select the available notebooks, I get a 500 Error and in the console I see the following:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'contextfilter' from 'jinja2' (/home/joesan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)
```

I tried to install and uninstall jinja2 but to no avail. How can I fix this?

Additional Info:

```
$ jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 7.27.0
ipykernel        : 6.4.1
ipywidgets       : 7.6.5
jupyter_client   : 7.0.3
jupyter_core     : 4.8.1
jupyter_server   : not installed
jupyterlab       : not installed
nbclient         : 0.5.4
nbconvert        : not installed
nbformat         : 5.1.3
notebook         : 6.4.4
qtconsole        : 5.1.1
traitlets        : 5.1.0

Opening in existing browser session.
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so init failed
/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py:257: UserWarning: date_default is deprecated since jupyter_client 7.0.0. Use jupyter_client.jsonutil.json_default.
  return _iterencode(o, 0)
[E 19:20:53.073 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /notebooks/boston_housing.ipynb (127.0.0.1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/notebooks/boston_housing.ipynb', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/joesan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1704, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "/home/joesan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 775, in run
        yielded = self.gen.send(value)
      File "/home/joesan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/notebook/handlers.py", line 95, in get
        self.write(self.render_template('notebook.html',
      File "/home/joesan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 516, in render_template
        return template.render(**ns)
      File "/home/joesan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1301, in render
        self.environment.handle_exception()
      File "/home/joesan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception
        raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
      File "/home/joesan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/templates/notebook.html", line 1, in top-level template code
        {% extends "page.html" %}
      File "/home/joesan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/templates/page.html", line 154, in top-level template code
        {% block header %}
      File "/home/joesan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/templates/notebook.html", line 115, in block 'header'
        {% for exporter in get_frontend_exporters() %}
      File "/home/joesan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/notebook/handlers.py", line 23, in get_frontend_exporters
        from nbconvert.exporters.base import get_export_names, get_exporter
      File "/home/joesan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
        from .exporters import *
      File "/home/joesan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from .html import HTMLExporter
      File "/home/joesan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/html.py", line 14, in <module>
        from jinja2 import contextfilter
    ImportError: cannot import name 'contextfilter' from 'jinja2' (/home/joesan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)
```

I'm using pyenv to manage environments:

```
$ pyenv versions
  system
  3.8.0
* 3.11.5 (set by /home/joesan/.pyenv/version)
```

Comment: Did you try upgrading nbconvert? Your issue is reminiscent of [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/500-internal-server-error-jinja2-related/13878/3?u=fomightez) and that happened to be the solution there. That is just a guess based on the limited information you've provided. The full traceback  would help more.

Comment: Nope! That did not help! I have edited my post with the full stack trace.

Comment: Yes, but since you have a mix, are you sure you updated correct one? The downgrading route of satyamedh may be one to try, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'contextfilter' from 'jinja2' (/home/joesan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)
```

It refers to `jinja2` from Python 3.8, while your Python version is 3.11. I am guessing `jupyter` is not installed in your Python 3.11 environment, but it is anyway present on the `PATH` of your operating system. Since now we have this weird mix of 3.8 and 3.11, you encounter import errors.

Solution:

1. Make sure you have isolated environments
2. Install `jupyter` to your 3.11

Comment: Yes, I'm using pyenv to manage environments.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, but according to your stack trace,

```
nbconvert        : not installed
```

As I found with [this comment on github](https://github.com/BIG-MAP/PRISMA/issues/2#issuecomment-1156182701), you either need to install `jinja==3.0` or `nbconvert`!